# Using a Conda Environment in Jupyter via Miniconda

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda, environment, miniconda

Has anyone found a way to successfully set up an environment for a jupyter notebook without having the full version of Anaconda installed on your system? I am using Miniconda and have been unable to use a conda environment with the jupyter notebook platform. Note that with Miniconda `source activate myenv` will not work.

I also tried using ipykernel which did successfully get an environment to appear in my notebook (via the command: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv`). However, this environment is still made as a copy of my base environment. Commands similar to `conda create -n test_env python=3.7` don't seem to be compatible with ipykernel unless I am missing something.

Comment: A semi-working solution to my own question. If I install `ipykernel` in my conda environment and then run `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv` within that active environment, I can use that environment within jupyter notebook. However the environment still isn't "clean" as it contains the 12 or so dependencies for `ipykernal`.

Comment: `ipykernel` is the dependency for running any env as a kernel in Jupyter, so that's as clean as you can get it.

Comment: From my continuing research here that is what I found as well. You need at least ipykernel, which is considerably lighter than jupyter in general.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run ipython from the environment you are adding.

Since you've got an environment with jupyter, lets call that Jenv.

go to your miniconda install location

`Scripts/activate Jenv
conda create -n SomeOther_vEnv python=3.6.8 whateverPackagesYouWant
python -m ipykernel install --sys-prefix --name SomeOther_vEnv --display-name "foo"`

Now jupyter when started from your Jenv should see "foo". You can't start jupyter from foo, but you can use it in a jupyter server started from Jenv. (unless whateverPackagesYouWant included jupyter of course)

Comment: As far as I understand it, what you suggest will end up registering the env `Jenv` (not `SomeOther_vEnv`) as a kernel, but giving it the name `SomeOther_vEnv` inside the `kernelspec` folder, and the name `foo` in the Jupyter GUI. This is because the flag `--sys-prefix` resolves to whatever the prefix of the currently activate env is and in your code this is still `Jenv`.

Comment: merv is correct. If you want to register a virtual env with Jupyer, that env at a minimum is going to need ipython.

Activate THAT env, then register it.